# When should I define child component in Angular modules instead of using selectors in parent component?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular5

I could not understand why we need child component in Angular?

Because we can use selectors and we can get the view of other components.
so When will we need defining children at routing definitions on app.module?

***What is the difference of above code and below code in aspect of defining children and navigation?***

**parent-component.html**

```
</div>  

<nested></nested>

</div>
```

**child-component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'nested',
  templateUrl: './nested-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./nested-component-list.component.css']
})
```

If we can achieve this without any definition on app.module (suppose that 2 component is in same angular module - app.module I have), what is the purpose of using chidren and defining children routes?

In app.module

```
path: 'parent-component', //<---- parent component declared here
      component: ParentComponent,
      children: [ 
        {
          path: 'child-one',
          component: ChildComponent
        } 
........
```

and in 
**parent-component.html*

```
 <div>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
```

and in

```
**parent-component.ts**
this.m_Router.navigate(["/child-one"]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already know what component is the child of your main component, then indeed you are better off just putting your `nested` component as you did.

Routing kicks in when you don't statically know what component will be included, and it is determined by the visited page.

For example, you could have your page:

```
<main-menu-and-page>
  <app-nested-page></app-nested-page>
</main-menu-and-page>
```

But `app-nested-page` needs to be `home-page`, or `about-page` depending on the visited url. In this case, you need the router and use:

```
<main-menu-and-page>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</main-menu-and-page>
```

with the proper routes definitions.

Comment: This is the answer I am looking for.  So I understood this but can we use router-outlet  instead of using selector because we wanted to explicitly define and able to see parent-children relationships (I mean to use router-outlet we have to define children - parent routing relation in app.module - or route.module if you write specific one  )

Comment: yes, feel free to use any method that suits your design and thinking.

Comment: What do you advice about defining all routes in one module and never use selector? Is it worth to work on? Because when someone examines the code, he / she can have knowledge about children and parents, if we use selector, person who reads our code, wont have this opportunity.

Comment: My advice is to always look for locality: if someone wants to know what is inside component A, the best place to look is in component A - not look up all routers to expand all `router-outlet` redirections. So I would advise to keep router calls to a low number - really when it makes sense - and to use composition inside components code when it really is the "structure" of the component you are building.

Comment: (Please consider upvote/accept this answer if you think it answers your question - it helps future viewers and people won't look here to answer your question because it is solved)

Comment: So If I have a case that nested component that will be always viewed  in  parent, you advice using selector but when I have a circumstance  that a child component will be the part of parent conditionaly, it had better us to use router (for example in a case that when we click some button , child will be triggered and seemable )instead of managing with directives such as ngif

Comment: No, in that case you should use `ngIf`. The use for router is when you change the navigate to a new `url`, not when you interact with stuff on the page.

Comment: In fact yes I will navigate a new url, my design is like that , I have a selector component and when user is clicked select button ,  In below list component has to be seen. I designed this in a way that I  defined parent component for selector and defined child component for list.  2  component must be seen in same area.  What is the best method to achieve this?

Comment: If you do `router.navigate`, use a `router`. If you don't, then use component. It really is a matter of taste and feeling, but all depends on this architecture of your app, I can't tell knowing that little. My guess is that you should go with straight components and not a router, but then again I can't tell for sure. (Router is rather for a choice between different set of components, if it's just for one it is more appropriate to go with a ngIf).

Answer (score -1):

simple example :
    i have a  project  (admin panel)
    and i am using date filter in every listing 
    so i will create a shared component date-filter.component.ts 
    and i will use it in every component without repeating code

**date-filter.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatDatepickerInputEvent } from '@angular/material';

interface IDate {
  label: string,
  fromDate: FormControl,
  toDate: FormControl
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-date-filter',
  templateUrl: './date-filter.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./date-filter.component.scss']
})
export class DateFilterComponent implements OnInit {

  minDate: Date;
  @Input() dateObject: IDate;
  constructor() { }
  maxDate: Date;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.maxDate = new Date();
  }

  /*
    Method For Detecting Filter From Date Change
  */
  dateChange(event: MatDatepickerInputEvent<Date>) {
    let dateValue = event.value;
    let minFromDate = new Date(dateValue);
    this.minDate = new Date(minFromDate.getFullYear(), minFromDate.getMonth(), minFromDate.getDate());
    this.dateObject.toDate.setValue('');

  }

  setToDate() {
    if (this.dateObject.toDate.value) {
      let to = new Date(this.dateObject.toDate.value);
      to.setHours(23);
      to.setMinutes(59);
      to.setSeconds(59);
      this.dateObject.toDate.setValue(to)
    }
  }
}
```

**date-filter.component.html**

```
  <h4>{{dateObject.label}}</h4>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput [max]="maxDate" [matDatepicker]="picker1" [formControl]="dateObject.fromDate" (click)="picker1.open()"
              (dateChange)="dateChange($event)" placeholder="From Date" readonly>
            <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker1"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
            <mat-datepicker #picker1></mat-datepicker>
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <mat-form-field>
            <input #toDate [max]="maxDate" matInput [formControl]="dateObject.toDate" (dateChange)="setToDate()" [min]="minDate"
              [matDatepicker]="picker2" (click)="picker2.open()" placeholder="To Date" readonly>
            <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker2"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
            <mat-datepicker #picker2></mat-datepicker>
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>
      </div>
```

**main-component.html**

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
        <app-date-filter [dateObject]="filterObject.registrationDate">
        </app-date-filter>
      </div>
```

Comment: Thanks but I ve already posted the same thing with you. I asked we define children: in app.module , but when we need this? We can use selector in components like I ve written sample code and you mentioned with the same way?

Comment: OP's question is really about the advantage of using routing instead of plain component integration.